# How do I improve wireless connectivity on my MacBook running Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, mac, wireless-networking, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu on my MacBook and it's great. The only problem is the Internet speed... on Mac OS X it is much faster which doesn't surprise me because both have been optimized to run fast.

I was wondering if there was a driver, or similar, that would improve the speed for Ubuntu?

Comment: How do you evaluate this problem?
Any iperf test or speed test?
Which kind / brand / model of network adapter you have?

Answer (score 0):

Does your wireless get slower after resuming from suspend or on battery?  If so, this information may help to disable the power saving features for your wireless adapter.

[Disabling wireless power management in Ubuntu](http://uselessuseofcat.com/?p=67)